# Given functional equation $f(x,y)=f(x,y+1)+f(x+1,y)+f(x-1,y)+f(x,y-1)$, show that $f(0,0)=0$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$, such that
for all $x,y$
$$f(x,y)=f(x,y+1)+f(x+1,y)+f(x-1,y)+f(x,y-1),$$
and if $m,n\in \mathbb{Z},mn\neq 0$,we have $f(2m,2n)=0$.

Show that
$$f(0,0)=0.$$

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult ["How to ask a good question?"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You should edit $f(x,y):\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ to $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Thailandasw What competition is this from?

Answer (score 7):

If this is true then there is a "finitary" proof, i.e. you can use the relations to express $f(0,0)$ as a finite linear combination of the $f(2n,2m)$.

First, here is a way to rephrase the problem in terms only of even entries of $f$, i.e. how to find a relation between $f(x,y),f(x+2,y),f(x,y+2),\ldots$

Consider $R = \Bbb R[X,X^{-1},Y,Y^{-1}]$ and let $P = (X+Y+X^{-1}+Y^{-1}-1)$.

$R$ is the set whose elements are finite linear combinations of monomials of the form $X^{\pm n} Y^{\pm m}$, and you can rephrase the goal by asking if there is an element $Q \in R$ such that $Q \times P$ has a nonzero constant coefficient and whose other nonzero coefficients occur only for exponents $(2n,2m)$ with nonzero $nm$.

Since $Q \times P$ is in $\Bbb R(X^2,Y^2)$ it is invariant by the Galois group $G$ of $\Bbb R(X,Y)$ over $\Bbb R(X^2,Y^2)$. $G$ has order $4$ and is given by the automorphisms $(X,Y) \mapsto (\pm X, \pm Y)$.

This tells us that $Q \times P$ has to be of the form $Q'(X^2,Y^2) \times P'(X^2,Y^2)$ where $P'(X^2,Y^2) = Norm(P) = P(X,Y)P(-X,Y)P(X,-Y)P(-X,-Y) $

You can easily compute $P'(X^2,Y^2) = (X^4 + Y^4 + X^{-4} + Y^{-4}) - 2(X^2Y^2 + X^2Y^{-2} + X^{-2}Y^{-2} + X^{-2}Y^2) - 2(X^2+Y^2+X^{-2}+Y^{-2}) -3$.

---

This gives you the relations between the even entries of $f$, and now with this new polynomial, the problem reduces to finding $Q'$ such that $Q' \times P'$ has a nonzero constant coefficient and a zero coefficient in front of $X^n$ and $Y^m$.

Start with $1 \times P'$. It has a nonzero constant coefficient (-3) so we just have to "push out" the $8$ extra unwanted nonzero coefficients.

To do this, first add some $-\frac 29(X+Y+X^{-1}+Y^{-1}) \times P'$. This should make the $4$ entries near the constant coefficient zero while still keeping the constant coefficient nonzero (it is $-11/9$).

Next, by symmetry reasons you can remove the $X^{\pm2},Y^{\pm2}$ coefficients by adding a suitable multiple of $(X^2Y^2+X^{-2}Y^{-2}) \times P'$ without touching the constant and neighbouring coefficients.

Finally you can remove the remaining nonzero coefficients of $X^n$ one at a time by adding multiples of $X^nY^2  \times P'$ and similarly for $Y^n$.

---

Computing the resulting polynomial gives you an explicit relation between $f(0,0)$ and a finite linear combination of some $f(2n,2m)$ with $nm \neq 0$, as needed.

Answer (score 3):

My GNU Maxima script below,

a) Can't find a unique solution if its size parameter $N$ satisfies $N \le 6$.

b) Is able to prove $f(0,0) = 0$ if its size parameter $N$ satisfies $N \ge 7$.

c) Is able to prove $f(0,0) = 0$ if its size parameter $N$ satisfies $N \ge 3$

and one changes the constraint from
$(mn \neq 0)$ into $(m \neq 0 \vee n \neq 0)$.

```
display2d : false;

/* variable construction */
my_v(f,m,n) := block(
    [res:[]],

    if (m < 0) and (n < 0) then block(
        res : concat(f,"m",-m,"m",-n)
    ),
    if (m < 0) and (n >= 0) then block(    
        res : concat(f,"m",-m,"p",+n)
    ),
    if (m >= 0) and (n < 0) then block(
        res : concat(f,"p",+m,"m",-n)
    ),
    if (m >= 0) and (n >= 0) then block(
        res : concat(f,"p",+m,"p",+n)
    ),

    return(res)
);

N : 7;
eqs : [];
for m : -N thru +N do block(
for n : -N thru +N do block(
    if (m*n # 0) then block(
        eqs : cons(my_v(f,2*m,2*n)=0,eqs)
    ),
    eqs : cons(my_v(f,m,n)
                = my_v(f,m,n-1) + my_v(f,m,n+1)
                    + my_v(f,m-1,n) + my_v(f,m+1,n), eqs)
));
print(eqs);
sols : algsys(eqs,listofvars(eqs));
s : sols[1];
for k thru length(s) do block(
    if listofvars(rhs(s[k])) = [] then block(
        print(k,"|",s[k])
    )
);

subst(s,fp0p0);
```

Switching off the generation of $f(2m,2n)=0$ in the above script
and many variable eliminations later,

I have the following distilled equation, still symmetric in the arguments of f

$$
46 f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
+13 f(-6,-2)
-26 f(-4,-4)
+13 f(-2,-6)\\
+13 f(+6,+2)
-26 f(+4,+4)
+13 f(+2,+6)\\
 -6 f(-8,+2)
-20 f(-4,-2)
-20 f(-2,-4)
 -6 f(+2,-8)\\
 -6 f(-2,+8)
-20 f(+2,+4)
-20 f(+4,+2)
 -6 f(+8,-2)\\
+24 f(-6,+2)
 +5 f(-2,-2)
+24 f(+2,-6)\\
+24 f(-2,+6)
 +5 f(+2,+2)
+24 f(+6,-2)\\
 +6 f(-6,+4)
+18 f(-4,+2)
+18 f(-2,+4)
 +6 f(+4,-6)\\
 +6 f(-4,+6)
+18 f(+2,-4)
+18 f(+4,-2)
 +6 f(+6,-4)\\
+34 f(-2,+2)
+34 f(+2,-2).
$$

from which the result follows.$\Box$

So this was somehow an algorithmic proof, the mathematical one follows now.

Additional symmetrization of the last equation gives
$$
92 f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
-6 f(+8,+2)
+6 f(+6,+4)
+6 f(+4,+6)
-6 f(+2,+8)\\
-6 f(-8,-2)
+6 f(-6,-4)
+6 f(-4,-6)
-6 f(-2,-8)\\
+37 f(+6,+2)
-26 f(+4,+4)
+37 f(+2,+6)\\
+37 f(-6,-2)
-26 f(-4,-4)
+37 f(-2,-6)\\
-6 f(+8,-2)
-2 f(+4,+2)
-2 f(+2,+4)
-6 f(-2,+8)\\
-6 f(-8,+2)
-2 f(-2,-4)
-2 f(-4,-2)
-6 f(+2,-8)\\
+37 f(+6,-2)
+39 f(+2,+2)
+37 f(-2,+6)\\
+37 f(+2,-6)
+39 f(-2,-2)
+37 f(-6,+2)\\
+6 f(+6,-4)
-2 f(+4,-2)
-2 f(-2,+4)
+6 f(-4,+6)\\
+6 f(+4,-6)
-2 f(+2,-4)
-2 f(-4,+2)
+6 f(-6,+4)\\
-26 f(+4,-4)
+39 f(+2,-2)
+39 f(-2,+2)
-26 f(-4,+4).
$$
Which can be reordered to
$$
92 f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(8\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(6\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+6 f(4\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)
-6 f(2\sigma_x,8\sigma_y)\\
+37 f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
-26 f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+37 f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
-2 f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
-2 f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+39 f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

This shall be our inspiration for the following definition
$$
I(a,b,c,d)\\
:= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(8\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(6\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+6 f(4\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)
-6 f(2\sigma_x,8\sigma_y)\\
+(c+37) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-26) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+37) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

On the following pages!! we will set the parameters $a,b,c,d$ as needed.

Removing the degree 10 terms gives
$$
I(a,b,c,d)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(7\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(7\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
+6 f(7\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(2\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)
+6 f(3\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(6\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+6 f(4\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(c+43) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-26) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+43) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+6 f(6\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-6 f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(3\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)
-6 f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(7\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(7\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(2\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)\\
+(c+37) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-26) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+37) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 9 terms gives
$$
I(a,b,c,d)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+6 f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+12 f(6\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-6 f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+12 f(3\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)
-6 f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(7\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)\\
+(c+31) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-26) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+31) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-12 f(4\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-12 f(5\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
-12 f(3\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-12 f(4\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
+6 f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(7\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)\\
+(c+31) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-26) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+31) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
+6 f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(7\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+6 f(1\sigma_x,7\sigma_y)\\
+(c+31) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(d-38) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+31) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

The idea is now to remove degree by degree until nothing of positive degree is left.

Removing the degree 8 terms gives
$$
I(a,b,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+12 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
-6 f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+12 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
+6 f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+(c+25) f(6\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
-(2c+38) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+25) f(2\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-2) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-2) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-(c+31) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+31) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+12 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
+(c+19) f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+12 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-(2c+38) f(4\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+(b-c-27) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-c-27) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-(c+19) f(4\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(2c+38) f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+31) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+31) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+12 f(6\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
+(c+19) f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
+12 f(1\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b-8) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-8) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 7 terms gives
$$
I(a,b,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-12 f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-12 f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-12 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(4\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(2c+38) f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(c+7) f(5\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+7) f(2\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+(b-8) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b-8) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-(c+7) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
-(c+7) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-12 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
-(2c+26) f(4\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)
-(2c+26) f(3\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(2c+38) f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b+c-1) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b+c-1) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+19) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-12 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+12 f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-6 f(6\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,6\sigma_y)\\
+(b+c-1) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b+c-1) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

We need another intermediate step, which we call $(*)$. We have for $n\ge 3$
$$
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
f(0\sigma_x,n\sigma_y)+f(n\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
)\\
=\\
+f(-0,-n)+f(-0,+n)+f(+0,-n)+f(+0,+n)\\
+f(-n,-0)+f(-n,+0)+f(+n,-0)+f(+n,+0)\\
=\\
+2f(0,-n)+2f(0,+n)+2f(-n,0)+2f(+n,0)\\
=\\
+2f(0,-n+1)-2f(0,-n+2)-2f(-1,-n+1)-2f(+1,-n+1)
+2f(0,+n-1)-2f(0,+n-2)-2f(-1,+n-1)-2f(+1,+n-1)
+2f(-n+1,0)-2f(-n+2,0)-2f(-n+1,-1)-2f(-n+1,+1)
+2f(+n-1,0)-2f(+n-2,0)-2f(+n-1,-1)-2f(+n-1,+1)\\
=\\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+f(0\sigma_x,(n-1)\sigma_y)+f((n-1)\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
+f(0\sigma_x,(n-2)\sigma_y)+f((n-2)\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-2f(1\sigma_x,(n-1)\sigma_y)-2f((n-1)\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
).
$$

With the help of $(*)$ this gives
$$
I(a,b,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-6 f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
-6 f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
+(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+19) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-18 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(c+19) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-18 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+12 f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c+7) f(5\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(c+7) f(1\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+(b+c-1) f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(b+c-1) f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 6 terms gives
$$
I(a,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(c+7) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+(c+7) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c+1) f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c+1) f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(c+19) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+19) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(2c+26) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-18 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(2c+26) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-18 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+12 f(3\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+6 f(4\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+6 f(2\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(c+1) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+1) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c+1) f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c+1) f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(c+25) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+25) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(2c+26) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-18 f(5\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)\\
-(2c+26) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)
-18 f(0\sigma_x,5\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

With the help of $(*)$ this gives
$$
I(a,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-18 f(3\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
-18 f(0\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c+1) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+1) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c-17) f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c-17) f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(c+25) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(c+25) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(2c-10) f(4\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(2c-10) f(1\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 5 terms gives
$$
I(a,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(2c-10) f(2\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+(2c-10) f(1\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
+(2c-28) f(3\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(2c-28) f(0\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c-11) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-12 f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
-(c-11) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c-17) f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c-17) f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(3c+15) f(3\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)
+(3c+15) f(2\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(a+39) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y))\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
-(c+25) f(2\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(c+25) f(1\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
+(2c-28) f(3\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(2c-28) f(0\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(c-11) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(c-11) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(c-17) f(4\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c-17) f(0\sigma_x,4\sigma_y)\\
+(a+3c+42) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

With the help of $(*)$ this gives
$$
I(a,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(c-17) f(2\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(c-17) f(0\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
-(c+25) f(2\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(c+25) f(1\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
+(3c-45) f(3\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(3c-45) f(0\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
-(3c-45) f(3\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(3c-45) f(1\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)\\
+(a+3c+42) f(2\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 4 terms gives
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(4c-62) f(2\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(6c-90) f(1\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+(4c-62) f(0\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
-(4c-20) f(2\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(4c-20) f(1\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
+(3c-45) f(3\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(3c-45) f(0\sigma_x,3\sigma_y)).
$$

With the help of $(*)$ this gives
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(3c-45) f(1\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(3c-45) f(0\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
+(7c-107) f(2\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(6c-90) f(1\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+(7c-107) f(0\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)\\
-(10c-110) f(2\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
-(10c-110) f(1\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

Removing the degree 3 terms gives
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
\sum_{\sigma_x,\,\sigma_y\in\{-1,+1\}}
(
+(13c-155) f(1\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
+(13c-155) f(0\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)\\
+(7c-107) f(2\sigma_x,0\sigma_y)
-(4c-20) f(1\sigma_x,1\sigma_y)
+(7c-107) f(0\sigma_x,2\sigma_y)).
$$

We are reaching the end of the proof. We need to remove the sum sign
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
(
+(26c-310) f(+1,+0)
+(26c-310) f(-1,+0)\\
+(26c-310) f(+0,+1)
+(26c-310) f(+0,-1)\\
+(14c-214) f(+2,+0)
+(14c-214) f(-2,+0)\\
-(4c-20) f(+1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(+1,-1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,-1)\\
+(14c-214) f(+0,+2)
+(14c-214) f(+0,-2)).
$$

Using the functional equation for the middle gives
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
(
+(14c-214) f(+2,+0)
+(14c-214) f(-2,+0)\\
-(4c-20) f(+1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(+1,-1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,-1)\\
+(14c-214) f(+0,+2)
+(14c-214) f(+0,-2)\\
+(26c-310) f(+0,+0)).
$$

On the other hand we have
$$
-3 x f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
-4 x f(+0,+0) + x f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
-4 x f(+0,+0)\\
+ x f(+2,+0) + x f(-2,+0) + x f(+0,+2) + x f(+0,-2)\\
+ 2x f(+1,+1) + 2x f(+1,-1) + 2x f(-1,+1) + 2x f(-1,-1)\\
+4 x f(+0,+0)\\
=\\
+ x f(+2,+0) + x f(-2,+0) + x f(+0,+2) + x f(+0,-2)\\
+ 2x f(+1,+1) + 2x f(+1,-1) + 2x f(-1,+1) + 2x f(-1,-1).
$$

Comparing now the coefficients of the $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ terms we get
$$
+(14c-214) = +x \\
-(4c-20) = +2x 
$$

Solving for $c,x$ we have $c=-51/4$ and $x=71/2$. Using these we finish the proof with
$$
I(-9c+48,-2c,c,-2c)\\
= \\
(
+(14c-214) f(+2,+0)
+(14c-214) f(-2,+0)\\
-(4c-20) f(+1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(+1,-1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,+1)
-(4c-20) f(-1,-1)\\
+(14c-214) f(+0,+2)
+(14c-214) f(+0,-2)\\
+(26c-310) f(+0,+0))\\
=\\
-3 x f(+0,+0) +(26c-310) f(+0,+0))\\
=\\
-213/2 f(+0,+0) - 1283/2 f(+0,+0)\\
= -748 f(+0,+0).
$$
Thus we have written $f(0,0)$ as a linear combination of the known vanishing terms even without using the vanishing property. $\Box$

I hope there are no typos somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sketching a solution since there is a lot of tedium required. This method finds all solutions $f$; perhaps there is a shortcut to show only $f(0, 0) = 0$?

1. Show that if $f$, $g$ are solutions, then $f + g$ is a solution as well. Easy from the condition.
2. Show that if$$f(3, 4) = f(4, 3) = f(3, 6) = f(6, 3) = 0,$$then $f(x, y) = 0$ for all $x$, $y$. To show this, notice that$$f(3, 3) + f(5, 3) = 0$$from $(x, y) = (4, 3)$ in the condition, and$$f(3, 3) + f(3, 5) = 0$$from $(x, y) = (3, 4)$ in the condition. So $f(3, 5) = f(5, 3)$. Then since$$f(5, 3) + f(5, 5) = f(5, 4)$$and $$f(3, 5) + f(5, 5) = f(4, 5),$$we have $f(5, 4) = f(4, 5)$. Finally,$$f(5, 4) + f(4, 5) = 0$$from $(x, y) = (4, 4)$ in the condition, so$$f(5, 4) = f(4, 5)=0.$$This logic is the hardest step needed; showing all the other values have to be $0$ is long, but each step is either repeating what we just did or applying the original condition where four of the terms are $0$.
3. Show that if we treat $f$ as a function on the plane, then the following $4 \times 6$ array is a solution when tessellated infinitely, aligned so the top left corner is $(0, 0)$. Here, $a$ is an arbitrary real.$$\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & a & 0 & -a & -a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -a & -a & 0 & a & a\end{matrix}$$
4. Show that if $f(3, 4)$, $f(4, 3)$, $f(3, 6)$, $f(6, 3)$ are arbitrarily set to real numbers, then there exists a solution. This is easy using step 1 and various transposes/translations of step 3.
5. Using steps 1 and 2, we have that if $f(3, 4)$, $f(4, 3)$, $f(3, 6)$, $f(6, 3)$ are specified, then there is at most one solution $f$. This means that step 4 describes all possible solutions. These solutions all satisfy $f(2m, 2n) = 0$ for all $m$, $n$, so we are done.

Comment: +1 Really beautiful and elementary solution. Thank you Brian!!